# How to skip first two line of CSV in Oracle Loader

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a requirement where I suppose to load the csv file using Oracle Loader. But this csv file have first two line as header and we want to exclude it in load. 
How we can skip it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [11g SQL Loader documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1004788) states that in your control file, you should just make sure you have an options clause.  Here is an example of how you could implement this:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=2)
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'my_new_records.csv'
BADFILE 'my_new_records.bad'
DISCARDFILE 'my_new_records.dsc'
APPEND
...
```

Comment: Thanks.
Is it possible to add simple SQL and and amend the record before the insert/append fired.